# Check if a socket is busy or not

Tags: python, subprocess, python-sockets

I am new to Socket Programming in Python. I have written the following code in Python 3.7:

**trialSocketList.py**

```
import subprocess
import sys

HOST = sys.argv[1]
PORT = sys.argv[2]

command = "tnc " + HOST + " -PORT "
print(command)
subprocess.call(command + PORT)
```

I am passing the following in the Windows CMD:

```
python trialSocketList.py "127.0.0.1" 445
```

But I am having the following error while executing the above code:

```
tnc 127.0.0.1 -PORT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trialSocketList.py", line 14, in <module>
    subprocess.call(command + PORT)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 323, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

When I try `netstat -an` instead of the command `tnc 127.0.0.1 -PORT` in the same code, the code functions perfectly. I have written the above few lines of code after reading [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) API.

**I can run `tnc` command if I hit it directly in Windows cmd.*

Am I missing something here? Or is there any other better way of doing this? If so, then please help me understand the issue here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tnc` is a [PowerShell command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=win10-ps). You'll need to explicitly run it with PowerShell like this:

```
import subprocess
import sys

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 445
command = "tnc " + HOST + " -PORT " + str(PORT)
print(command)
subprocess.call(["powershell.exe",command],stdout=sys.stdout)
```

Output:

```
tnc 127.0.0.1 -PORT 445

ComputerName     : 127.0.0.1
RemoteAddress    : 127.0.0.1
RemotePort       : 445
InterfaceAlias   : Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
SourceAddress    : 127.0.0.1
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `Popen` with `shell=True`. Here is how your code would look with that:

```py
import subprocess
import sys

HOST = sys.argv[1]
PORT = sys.argv[2]

command = "tnc " + HOST + " -PORT "
print(command)
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=tempFile, shell=True)
```

[Here](https://bugs.python.org/issue17023) is the listed issue.

Comment: What is tempFile here? I am new to Python, so its difficult to understand that link.

Comment: Although I tried to define `tempFile` as a file with `w+` mode. But that left the file empty and the error in the cmd remained the same. The file created was also empty

Comment: @Code_Ninja -- All the temp file does is, put the output of the command in it.

Comment: okay, I tried to open the file as `tempFile = open("tempFile.txt",  "w+")`, this created the file nicely, but the situation with the running of command remained the same.

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that the python script can't find the `tnc` program.  Either the program is not installed at all, or---if it is installed---it isn't in the PATH variable.

Comment: But, I can run the same from the cmd window or the powershell.

Comment: You never said you could run it at all.  At least that means `tnc` is installed.  The fact that you can run it from the command line says that there is something going on when it tries to find the program in your path variable.  You can try specifying the full path as part of the subprocess call or you can try setting `shell=True`.  Also, how is it in your path?  There is also this:  https://bugs.python.org/issue17023

Comment: The path is in not in quotes, I will try `shell=True`.

Comment: But since I am using windows, will `shell=True` be applicable? I thought its for Unix/Linux systems only.

Comment: It is still applicable. It will use something like `cmd` to execute instead of just creating a new process like the `subprocess.call()` w/o `shell=True`.

Comment: `shell=True` didn't help.